# When running code, sorting method prints same exact array numbers when the second array should be sorted in ascending or descending order

Tags: java

The code below is in the `selectionSorting` method which is just a specific way of sorting. I think the problem is somewhere here but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```java
if(orderAscending.isSelected()) {
    boolean sorted = false;
    int counting = arrayInt.length-1;
    int errorCounter = 1;
    int tempNum;
    while(sorted == false) {
        if(errorCounter == 0) {
            sorted = true;
        }else {
            errorCounter = 0;
        }
        if(arrayInt[counting] < arrayInt[counting - 1] && sorted != true) {
            tempNum = arrayInt[counting];
            arrayInt[counting] = arrayInt[counting - 1];
            arrayInt[counting - 1] = tempNum;
            errorCounter++;
            counting--;
        }
        if (counting == 0) {
            counting  = arrayInt.length-1;
        }
    }
    String sOutput = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length-1; i++) {
        sOutput = sOutput + arrayInt[i] + "\n";
    }
    sortedOutput.setText(sOutput);
```

Output

[image: output]

Comment: errorCounter is set  a default value of 1 during variable declaration and it's value is never reduced. But, sorted gets set to true only when errorCounter is zero where as errorCounter value never goes down below one. You may revisit the sorting logic or instead use Arrays.sort() java APIs

Comment: @PrithviRajMundur he is checking errorCounter by if statement and if the counter's value is greater than zero then its value is again set to zero using else statment, this is not the right approach because the loop may end by running just for one time.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop should only include this code

```
if(orderAscending.isSelected()) {
            boolean sorted = false;
            int counting = arrayInt.length-1;
            int errorCounter = 1;
            int tempNum,secondLoop;
            while(counting>0) {
                
               secondLoop=0;
             while(secondLoop<=counting){
                if(arrayInt[counting] < arrayInt[secondLoop]) {
                    tempNum = arrayInt[counting];
                    arrayInt[counting] = arrayInt[secondLoop];
                    arrayInt[secondLoop] = tempNum;
                }
              secondLoop++;
             }
                    counting--;
            }
            String sOutput = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length-1; i++) {
                sOutput = sOutput + arrayInt[i] + "\n";
            }
            sortedOutput.setText(sOutput);
```

Comment: I replaced my old code with this, but when running the code it seems to go infinitely, as the GUI freezes.

Comment: The code still seems to produce the same results.

Comment: Thank you, it seems a lot better now however, at the beginning of the outputted array it has the largest number at the beginning when it should be at the end. I can send a screenshot of the output, or upload the full code if that helps at all

Comment: what you want your array look like? you want to sort it like from smaller to greater?

Comment: Yeah, I need to be able to sort by ascending and descending. The code above is only the ascending portion of the code.

Comment: just change this line  if(arrayInt[counting] < arrayInt[secondLoop])   to this   if(arrayInt[counting] > arrayInt[secondLoop])

Comment: for ascending order the condition should be if(arrayInt[counting] < arrayInt[secondLoop]) and for descending order the condition will look like this if(arrayInt[counting] > arrayInt[secondLoop])

Comment: Changing from ascending to descending was as simple as a I figured, but I'm still having the problem with the output showing the first number of the original list at the beginning of the sorted list no matter if descending or ascending. The rest of the list is sorted correctly except for that.

Comment: Thanks it's working, you've been a big help